# How to change method names from jpa-repository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, repository

There is application on spring+jpa(repositories)
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private int age;
}
```

So, my repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{
  public List<User> findUsersByNameAndAge(String name, int age);
  public List<User> findUsersByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);
}
```

In my real prod code, there too much params, so this method-name is too long and not comfortable.
Is there a way to make from long method names comfortable options, like just find?

Comment: Use `@Query` to define your own query and name the methods whatever you want: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Use a query of use the `Criteria` API to generate your queries. The method names and translation to queries is only the simple use-cases.

Answer (score 8):

Use **default** Java 8 feature for wrapping :

for example :

```
   interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  // don't use that crazy long method! use getByEmail instead
  User findFirstByEmailContainsIgnoreCaseAndField1NotNullAndField2NotNullAndField3NotNullAndField4NotNullAndField5NotNullAndField6NotNull(final String email);

  default User getByEmail(final String email) {
    return findFirstByEmailContainsIgnoreCaseAndField1NotNullAndField2NotNullAndField3NotNullAndField4NotNullAndField5NotNullAndField6NotNull(email);
  }
}
```

You can find complete reference here : https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-examples/blob/master/shadov/src/main/java/daggerok/ShadovApplication.java

Or else You can specify any name for a method and add an annotation **@Query** with parameter value which holds desired query to database like this:

```
@Query(value="select u from User u where u.deleted=false and u.email=:email")
User findOneByEmail(@Param("email")String email);
or, with native sql query:

@Query(value="SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted=false AND email=?1", nativeQuery=true)
User findOneByEmail(String email);
```

You can also use names that follow the naming convention for queries since @Query annotation will take precedence over query from method name.