# Can I change method name in Spring Data JPA when using @Query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

For example, I have a big method name in Spring Data JPA interface.

Optional findByNameAndRestaurantIdAndDateAdded(String name, int restaurantId, LocalDate dateAdded);

If I add @Query, can I change it to something more readable?

```
     @Query("SELECT d FROM Dish d " +
         "WHERE d.name=?1 AND d.restaurant.id=?2 AND d.dateAdded=?3")
 Optional<Dish> someRandomNameIWant(String name, int restaurantId, LocalDate dateAdded);
```

Does name of the method have any meaning when @Query is added?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change method names from jpa-repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315452/how-to-change-method-names-from-jpa-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **you can**, as you defined your **own query** you do not use Spring Data's query derivation anymore

Comment: You might want to alter the statement to "…you do not use Spring Data's query derivation" anymore, as that's what's actually happening. Hibernate doesn't have anything to do with this.